# JSP Page redirection failed

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans

Im using Netbeans java. I met the problem whereby my pages would not flow in order. I have removed the links in my faces-config for this specific JSP page. I have inserted a refresh-redirect function in this JSP page, however it goes back to the previous page instead. I'm worried that its the problem with my Netbeans. Anyone met this problem before?

*The JSP page that I redirected to is accessible when the URL is typed in manually in IE

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<style type="text/css">
@import "site.css";
</style>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<f:view>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>Verification</title>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="2;http://localhost:8080/MajorProject-war/faces/Reviewer/ReviewerIndex.jsp">
    </head><body BGCOLOR="#E0E0E0" TEXT="#000080">
        <div class="background">

<b><big>Verification successful</b></big>
<br></br> Redirecting you to homepage...<br></br>
<h:form>


        </h:form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this url](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh), the value of the content attribute should be:

```
2; url=http://localhost:8080/MajorProject-war/faces/Reviewer/ReviewerIndex.jsp
```